# store.getRootField(...) returns null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, relay

I call an api to add a new request:

```
import { commitMutation, graphql } from "react-relay";

import { REQUEST_STATUS_NEW } from "../../../constants";

const mutation = graphql`
  mutation CreateRequestMutation($input: CreateRequestInput!) {
    createRequest(input: $input) {
      request {
        id
        tid
        title
        description
        price
        commission
        value
        expirationDate
        createdAt
        completionDate
        multipleResponders
        draft
        status
        requestProposals
        type {
          id
          name
        }
        industry {
          id
          name
        }
        applications {
          id
        }
        myApplication {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

let tempId = 0;

function sharedUpdater(store, request) {
  const root = store.getRoot();
  const newRequests = root
    .getLinkedRecords("requests", { own: true })
    .filter(r => r);

  if (!newRequests.find(m => m.getValue("id") === request.getValue("id"))) {
    newRequests.push(request);
  }
  root.setLinkedRecords(newRequests, "requests", { own: true });
}

export const commit = (environment, input) => {
  tempId += 1;
  return commitMutation(environment, {
    mutation,
    variables: { input },
    updater: store => {
      const payload = store.getRootField("createRequest");
      console.log('payload: ', payload)
      const request = payload.getLinkedRecord("request");
      sharedUpdater(store, request);
    }
  });
};
```

But each time I call it, store.getRootField return me null. I cant really understand where is the problem where I can investigate further. Any help appreciated. Seems like server doesnt have any issues at their side. How can I debug this?

Comment: But is the mutation running correctly? What do you get on `console.log('payload: ', payload)` ?

Comment: In my opinion, you should do this `sharedUpdater` treatment/verifications on your server, and not after the mutation already ran. You should return the data that you know you want to update the store with. This is just a suggestion though